# From below to time of need

Tags: riddle, rhyme

From below I am born
Place me above and I shall sweat
Cut me and I do not bleed
Yet shed me in time of need

HINT

> an oven is formed when cut between sheets

Comment: Is it possible to accept an answer so this doesn't keep getting bumped up by people who haven't seen your intended answer?

Answer (score 19):

Perhaps you are

> ice?

From below I am born

> Ice forms when temperatures are below freezing.

Place me above and I shall sweat

> But if you put ice in temperatures that are above freezing, it melts again.

Cut me and I do not bleed

> Ice is only frozen water and does not bleed when cut.

Yet shed me in time of need

> The end of winter is a time of need for people (though somewhat less so in modern times) and animals who have used up their stores of food and supplies. But then spring comes, and the land sheds its snow and ice and living things begin to thrive again.

I doubt it, but I like the "above" and "below" correlation.

Comment: If you fix your explanation for "shed me in time of need" I could give this answer credit, although it's not what I thought when writing it initially, it does work.

Comment: @jmb.mage I tried what might be a better reason for the last line of the riddle. I'm still curious what the real answer is, though! I keep checking back to see if anyone has gotten it yet.

Comment: "shed in time of need" could be perspiration. "in time of need" could be either a tense situation or could be when we need to shed it i.e while running, etc.

Answer (score 15):

Are you

> hair

From below I am born

> Comes from under the skin through follicles

Place me above and I shall sweat

> A full head of hair will make you sweat.

Cut me and I do not bleed

> Hair has no blood capillaries, so it does not bleed when you cut it.

Yet shed me in time of need

> animals shed their fur when they get too hot, and grow more back when they get cold (winter/summer coats).

Comment: Similar answer to mine - but think this is more likely to be correct, I'm unsure about the bleeding bit in mine

Comment: You might want to add about summer and winter coats of fur for the last one

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil.  I expanded on a few parts.  The one that I am a little iffy on is the sweat part, because my answer doesn't sweat on its own.

Comment: These answers are great, but same as above.  Debatable because "Place me" involves a voluntary action.  And the purpose of your answer does not totally meet "in time of need".

Comment: I accept that this is not the answer, but I will dispute that "Place me" is automatically a voluntary (and apparently physical) action.  Placing something somewhere can be a mental/theoretical action ("I can't seem to place where I met you before")

Comment: "Place me" = wig

Answer (score 9):

Are you

> Grass

From below I am born

> It grows from the ground

Place me above and I shall sweat

> [Water from the grass will evaporate](http://www.cmmap.org/scienceEd/summercourse/summerCourse15/DoPlantsSweat.pdf)

Cut me and I do not bleed

> Grass doesn't bleed

Yet shed me in time of need

> Cut it when it gets too long so it looks nicer

Comment: This answer nearly works!  Although the sweat produced requires a second element.

Comment: Technically that's not sweat, it's transpiration

Answer (score 5):

Another guess:

> Daedalus's wings

From below I am born

> Daedalus made the wings when he was trapped in the Labyrinth, which is sometimes depicted as being underground.

Place me above and I shall sweat

> Daedalus warned his son Icarus that if he flew too high with the wings, they would melt from the heat of the sun.

Cut me and I do not bleed

> The wings were made of wax and feathers, not flesh and blood.

Yet shed me in time of need

> In spite of his father's warning, Icarus flew too high and inadvertently shed his wings by melting them apart when he needed them most.

Answer (score 5):

My Guess:

> Clouds

From below I am born

> Starts out as water on the ground that evaporates

Place me above and I shall sweat

> Evaporated water condenses as a cloud above and then rains down

Cut me and I do not bleed

> Clouds don't bleed when a plane flies through them

Yet shed me in time of need

> During a drought there isn't enough water vapor in the air for clouds to form

Last part is not as much of a stretch now, thanks whrrgarbl :)

Comment: Before I read all your explanations I was thinking about drought for the last clue, which could be less of a stretch. The rest seems pretty plausible to me!

Answer (score 4):

Might be

> Skin

From below I am born

> You have several layers of skin, the bottom layer slowly rises to the top and the skin tissue is created under you current top layers

Place me above and I shall sweat

> Top layer of skin sweats

Cut me and I do not bleed

> Skin itself can't bleed - you can pierce the top layer of your skin and there won't be any blood (not sure?)

Yet shed me in time of need

> Skin constantly flakes off - dust is created by dead skin

Comment: Debatable because "Place me" involves a voluntary action.  The purpose of your answer does not totally meet "in time of need".

Answer (score 3):

Still thinking about it, but might I guess:

> Fears / Worries

From below I am born

> Fears/Worries come from deep down inside, butterflies in the stomach or as if they come from within one's heart

Place me above and I shall sweat

> Place them above, i.e. in your head, and thinking about them makes you sweat

Cut me and I do not bleed

> Fears and worries often feel unassailable, or out of your power. You can try to fight the monster that is your fears/worries (cut it) but it will not help (will not bleed)

Yet shed me in time of need

> In dire circumstances, we drop our fears and worries to bravely do what needs to be done

Answer (score 1):

Maybe :

> A tree

Because :

"From below I am born"

> It grows from earth

"Place me above and I shall sweat"

> "Transpiration is the process of water movement through a plant and its evaporation from aerial parts, such as leaves, stems and flowers." From wikipedia, transpiration page

"Cut me and I do not bleed"

> Trees don't have blood but have sap or resin

"Yet shed me in time of need"

> For example to produce paper or do a fire

Answer (score 1):

Trying to think outside the box here:

> you are an athlete on the reserve roster for a team sport

From below I am born

> a roster of players can be organized with those playing at the top of the list and those on reserve at the bottom, with a line between (in general, most players new to a team start at the bottom)

Place me above and I shall sweat

> the coach places you "above" the reserve line. you are now an active player and will sweat from activity

Cut me and I do not bleed

> the coach can cut a player from the active roster at any time, which means they are placed back onto the reserve (no bleeding!)

Yet shed me in time of need

> a coach can completely remove a player from a team if they need to make room for other players (salary caps, etc.), or if they are underperforming team (to benefit the team)

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

> A potato

"From below I am born"

> You grow potatoes underground

"Place me above and I shall sweat"

> In sunlight potatoes 'sweat' and rot I believe (?)

"Cut me and I do not bleed"

> Potatoes don't bleed when cut

"Yet shed me in time of need"

> A good place to store potatoes is in a shed

Comment: I think you might've gotten your answer and explanation mixed up haha

Comment: Yes; I copied someone else's format to save time. Laziness never pays

Answer (score 0):

An answer that perhaps beats my previous answer of

> Fears / Worries

Is

> Flowers/Seedpods

From below I am born

> Seeds grow from the ground and sprout up

Place me above and I shall sweat

> Flowers/Seedpods 'sweat' either their pollen or seeds to disperse them

Cut me and I do not bleed

> Flowers/Seedpods and even their trees can be cut but do not bleed

Yet shed me in time of need

> Tree's shed their seeds / pollen to achieve their singular goal of reproduction

This un's a hard one

Answer (score 0):

This could be

> water

From below I am born

> Water is created under the surface of earth.

Place me above and I shall sweat

> Water in clouds "sweats" as rain.

Cut me and I do not bleed

> This refers to Water Cut, which is the ratio of produced water compared to the volume of the total produced fluids in a well.

Yet shed me in time of need

> Organisms "shed" the water if there is more than needed (sweating, urinating etc).

Answer (score -1):

Are you

> Skin

From below I am born

> Skin forms under the current top layer of skin

Place me above and I shall sweat

> The top layer of skin is able to sweat

Cut me and I do not bleed

> You only bleed if you are cut deep enough to penetrate through the skin

Yet shed me in time of need

> Most animals shed their skin over time

Comment: I've already said this

Answer (score -2):

I thought I'd give the answer I originally intended.  Although after consideration I believe @aprough answer may be the closest.

From below I am born

> Cheese comes from below a cow, it's also a rumor it was originally made in caves, below ground, or being left inside animal bladders.

Place me above and I shall sweat

> cheese left out will sweat

Cut me and I do not bleed

> cutting cheese does not bleed it

Yet shed me in time of need

> shedding cheese, or grating cheese, is often a way of using it, like parmigiana flakes

Comment: Did you mean shred?